# Multiplication Simplification in a Composition Function

Tags: elementary-functions

I am trying to work out $(\Pi \circ f)(L)$. The functions are defined:

> $ \Pi(y) = -y^4 + 6y^2 - 5 $, and $ f(L) = 5L^\frac23$

I understand the first simplification to:

> $-(5L^\frac23)^4 + 6(5L^\frac23)^2 - 5$

But I do not understand the final simplification. Specifically, I do not understand where 625 and 150 come from in the final equation below:

> $-625L^\frac83 + 150L^\frac43 - 5$

I can see that $625$ is $5^4 \times 5$, and that $125$ is $5^2 \times 5$, but I don't get why we have 625 and 150 in the equation, rather than just $-5L^\frac83$, for example. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Because $$(ab)^4=a^4b^4$$ and $$(cd)^2=c^2d^2$$

Answer (score 1):

You just got a mistake which probably confuses you: $5^4=625$ already. And $5^2=25$, but you still have to multiply with the factor $6$...
To take the exponent of a product, you have to multiply the exponents of each factor. You only took the exponent of the unknown variable.